# PDO invalid parameter number mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

hi i'm getting an invalid parameter number when executing php PDO select statement with `JOIN` and `LIKE` below is my code

```
try {
$search = ('SELECT torrents.ID,torrents.ImgUrl,torrents.Title,songs.Song from torrents INNER JOIN songs ON torrents.ID = songs.ID where torrents.Title Like :search_query or songs.Song Like :search_query');
$search = $a->prepare($search);
$search_query = "%$search_query%";
$search->execute(array(':search_query' => $search_query));
$search_query = $search->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I have tried using placeholders `torrents.Title Like ? OR songs.Song Like ?`and execute it with `$search->execute($search_query);` Still i'm getting an error.

Comment: With `PDO_MySQL` you cannot reuse a :named parameter. You need to bind it twice; with different names. Enumerated placeholders `?` might be advantageous here.

Comment: @mario how is this question a duplicate? just because they have the same heading?

Comment: How isn't it? Elaborate if your problem differs. What part of it is not applicable? Question uniqueness isn't about different variable names.

Comment: @mario the other one uses insert and mine uses multiple mysql statements.

Comment: You have just one query. This PDO constraint (depending on driver, PDO version, and EMULATE_PREPARES btw) isn't going to change depending on the statement clause. Also please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24855480/edit) instead of comments to add distinct infos on what you've tried or prior research.

Comment: Just needs `$search->execute(array($search_query, $search_query));` for two `?` placeholders.